# How to find weeks between two dates

Tags: vb.net, date

How to find week's starting date between two dates.

Example:

```
date1: 4th March 2014. 
date2: 18th March 2014.
```

Then it should return list of weeks begining date as 
`2014-03-03, 2014-03-10, 2014-03-17`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Function GetWeekStartDates(startDate As Date, endDate As Date) As List(Of Date)
    Dim result As New List(Of Date)
    Dim checkDate = startDate
    Dim Is1stWeek As Boolean = True
    Do While checkDate <= endDate
        If checkDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday Then
            result.Add(checkDate)
            If Is1stWeek Then Is1stWeek = False
        Else
            If Is1stWeek Then
                result.Add(checkDate.AddDays(-checkDate.DayOfWeek + 1))
                Is1stWeek = False
            End If
        End If
        checkDate = checkDate.AddDays(1)
    Loop
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, I've checked this code, works for the ranges you give - hope this is what you wanted!  There's probably a smarter way.

Answer (score 2):

So first you want to get the first day of the week of the start-date? This gives your desired list:

```
Dim firstDate = New Date(2014, 3, 4)
Dim daysToFirstDay As Int32 = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek - firstDate.DayOfWeek
firstDate = firstDate.AddDays(daysToFirstDay) ' -1 day in this case
Dim lastDate = New Date(2014, 3, 17)
Dim days As Int32 = (lastDate - firstDate).Days + 1 ' including last

Dim result As List(Of Date) = Enumerable.Range(0, days).
    Select(Function(d) firstDate.AddDays(d)).
    Where(Function(day) day.DayOfWeek = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek).
    ToList()
```

It's using LINQ to create a range of `Date`s between the start-and end-date. Then it uses the current `DateTimeFormatInfo's`  `FirstDayOfWeek` property to return only week-starting days.

Comment: I need weekstartdate as "Monday" date. Please share me how it could be achieve. and what should be "Days" in above code ? (would it be difference between FROM AND TO date ?)

Comment: @Dhaval: Have you tried above? It uses the `FirstDayOfWeek` of your current culture's `DateTimeFormat` which is `DayOfWeek.Monday` for me. So you could also simply replace `DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek` with `DayOfWeek.Monday` if you want. I just wanted to take into account that this might be different.

Comment: @Dhaval: note that i've edited my answer since it didn't include the first week's start-date if that was before the given start-date.